# How to remove escape character from solr indexed field?

Tags: solr

I am indexing Json data into solr field, for eg

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

But Json is getting indexed with escaped characters, so now I am getting the json as

```
  "{\"employees\":[\n    {\"firstName\":\"John\", \"lastName\":\"Doe\"},\n    {\"firstName\":\"Anna\", \"lastName\":\"Smith\"},\n    {\"firstName\":\"Peter\", \"lastName\":\"Jones\"}\n]}"
```

Is there any way to index without escaping the json or de escaping result while displaying from the solr end solely ?

Comment: Are you returning it as JSON and the value is in a single field? In that case, Solr would have to escape it, so that the value is kept safe within the field value. Your JSON library would then decode it so that "fieldname" has the value of the JSON string, which you'd then decode again.

Comment: Yes @MatsLindh indexing the json in single field only. I didn't get your last point i.e. "decoding" , would be kind enough to explain it in more detail .

Comment: When parsing the JSON, the escaping will be removed (as it is required for the result to be valid JSON). If the JSON is still escaped when retrieving it (after going through the library), it sounds like your JSON is being double escaped by the library when you're indexing.

Comment: @matslindh thanks, how to resolve this ? Any special tokenizer or analyzers or may be field type.. as m trying a basic json and indexing it via update from solr ui .

Comment: It's impossible to say - there's nothing inherent in Solr which should give you this problem. The result should be returned as it was submitted (as it's stored separetely from tokenizers/analyzers). You'll have to add more details to give a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly fine storage of json data in a solr textfield.
If you see it through admin, you will see the json in escaped format in the UI, but if you were to query this and then decode the json, it will return correct object in the language you are using.
Python example.

```
my_json_field =  json_string // read from solr using api calls or module like pysolr
my_obj = json.loads(my_json_field)
```

Comment: Thanks brother, But I need a pure solr solution not using pysolr or other stuffs

Comment: @DimagKharab  The point is that there is no issue at all, your json data is correctly stored in solr.

Comment: Yep bro, but need to get the unescaped json in result, as we want to one more parsing in the client side or api

Answer (score 0):

Finally solution was very simple by using [Transforming Result Documents](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Transforming+Result+Documents)

eg,

```
fl=my_field_with_escaped_json:[json]
```

Thanks everyone